# Selenium wait for clickable - still raises an exception

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have an issue with Selenium Webdriver wait & expected_conditions.

I try to click to a menu that seems to be obscured by a preloader script, so I try to wait for the element to be clickable, but I still have the issue.

here is my python code :

```
    menu = WebDriverWait(FF_driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "dropdownMenuButton")))
    menu.click()
```

when I run the code, it raises an exception :

`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <button id="dropdownMenuButton" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle i-want-to-button dropdown-toggle" type="button"> is not clickable at point (1366,130) because another element <div id="preloader"> obscures it`

I try to wait for preloader element to be invisible with :

```
WebDriverWait(FF_driver, 10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='preloader']")))
```

but without success..
What could I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are facing an issue where the element you want to click is being obscured by a preloader script. While you have attempted to wait for the preloader element to be invisible, it seems that the preloader is still causing problems.

Here are a few suggestions you can try:

1. Add a Longer Wait for Preloader:
   Increase the waiting time for the preloader to be invisible. Sometimes, the default timeout may not be enough. Try increasing it to see if it resolves the issue:

```
WebDriverWait(FF_driver, 30).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='preloader']")))
```

2. Use a Different Expected Condition:
   Instead of using invisibility_of_element_located, you can try using staleness_of, which waits for an element to become stale (not present or not visible).

```
preloader = FF_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='preloader']")
WebDriverWait(FF_driver, 30).until(EC.staleness_of(preloader))
```

3. Execute JavaScript to Click:
   If the above approaches don't work, you can resort to executing JavaScript to perform the click operation. This can sometimes bypass issues related to element visibility.

```
menu = WebDriverWait(FF_driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "dropdownMenuButton")))
FF_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", menu)
```

4. Scroll to Element Before Click:
   If the element is not in the viewport, scrolling to it before clicking might help.

```
menu = WebDriverWait(FF_driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "dropdownMenuButton")))
FF_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", menu)
menu.click()
```

5. Check for Overlay:
   Ensure that there are no other elements overlaying the element you want to click. If there is an overlay, you might need to handle it separately.
6. Debugging:
   Print the visibility status of the preloader before and after waiting for it to be invisible to see if it's behaving as expected.

```
preloader = FF_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='preloader']")
print("Preloader visibility before wait:", preloader.is_displayed())
WebDriverWait(FF_driver, 30).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='preloader']")))
print("Preloader visibility after wait:", preloader.is_displayed())
```

Try these suggestions, and hopefully, one of them will resolve the issue you are facing with the preloader obscuring the element.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/10871073

Answer (score 1):

Thanks !

I used 2 solutions

```
preloader = FF_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='preloader']")
WebDriverWait(FF_driver, 30).until(EC.staleness_of(preloader))
```

and

```
menu = WebDriverWait(FF_driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "dropdownMenuButton")))
FF_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", menu)
```

both are working !
thanks a lot